# Spring Boot :Deleting a blog posts shared tag only when the last post that has it is deleted

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a dilemma trying to get a solution for this issue. I have two (can be any number) blog posts that share the same tag.

I have a set of tags for each added post so duplicate tags are not possible, so lets say I add first post with the tags "car" and "blue" and the second post with "car" and "red". then I will have car, red, blue in the database tag table so car is only once but both posts share it which puts me in a situation of not being able to delete any of the 2 posts because of the shared tag.

How can I delete the tag only when the last post is deleted but not before(when I delete the first one)? I don't think there is any cascade type that can help me with this issue but I may be mistaken? (I have used All and Remove but that did not work)
What solution do I have?

I am using spring boot with MySQL.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

**L.E** : For anyone having the same issue, I have used
`cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}` on the Post(parent) Tag(child) many to many relationship. and using a loop to delete the remaining tags after the last post has been deleted. Everything works so far.

Comment: How about you keep a count of the tags used ? Each time a post deleted, you can decrement the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use orphan removal option but it reinserts depending associations when there is an active relationship. You can read [this blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/delete-with-hibernate#removal-of-orphans).

You can use event listeners and i recommend this. Write an event listener that works when a tag is deleted so with event listener you can conditionally delete the tags. You can read [this for event listeners](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events). You can use `@PostRemove` event.